# Find $AC$ WITHOUT using Cosine law...

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the following figure find side $AC$ WITHOUT using Cosine law:
>   [image]

There is a simple solution involving Cosine law,but is it possible to calculate $AC$ without using it??

Comment: I thought that you look for the solution without trigonometry completely. :)

Comment: Does the Pythagorean Theorem count as an application of the Law of Cosines?

Comment: I think it's a pure geometric theorem

Comment: @michael Rosenberg dear Michael, I appreciate your continuous contribution to my questions , and your method is very good , but unfortunately just one answer can be accepted.Also, any solution Not involving law of Cosines was good to me

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: The Law of Cosines is also a "pure geometric theorem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $BC=x$. Then $AC=\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Use the law of sines in triangle BCD to obtain

$$\frac{x}{\sin\angle D}=\frac{1}{\sin 30^\circ}=2.$$

Notice that $\angle ABD=120^\circ$, whose supplementary angle is $60^\circ$. So we have

$$ AB\times\sin 60^\circ=AD\times\sin\angle D.$$

We may plug in numbers to obtain

$$(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})\,\frac{x}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Here's the tricky part. In terms of $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, the equation becomes

\begin{align}
(1+y)\sqrt{y^2-1}&=\sqrt{3},\\
y^4+2y^3-2y-1&=3,\\
(y^3-2)(y+2)&=0.
\end{align}

The answer is $AC=2^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $DK$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABD$, $AC=x$ and $BD=y$.

Thus, $$DK=\frac{y\sqrt3}{2},$$ 
$$BK=\frac{y}{2}$$ and
$$BC=\sqrt{x^2-1}.$$

Thus, since $$\frac{AB}{BK}=\frac{AC}{CD}$$ and
$$\frac{BC}{DK}=\frac{AC}{AD},$$ we got the following system:
$$\frac{1}{\frac{y}{2}}=\frac{x}{1}$$ and
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\frac{y\sqrt3}{2}}=\frac{x}{x+1}.$$
Thus, $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\frac{\sqrt3}{x}}=\frac{x}{x+1}$$ or
$$\sqrt{x^2-1}(x+1)=\sqrt3$$ or
$$x^4+2x^3-2x-4=0$$ or
$$(x+2)(x^3-2)=0$$ or
$$x=\sqrt[3]{2}.$$

Comment: @MichaelRosenberg : Dear Michael ,by the way ,you used some  trigonometry  too:)

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi Where? In $\Delta BDK$ we have $\measuredangle BDK=30^{\circ}$, which says $BK=\frac{y}{2}$ and after using Pythagoras we obtain $DK=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}y$.

Comment: For example in: $DK=\frac{y\sqrt3}{2}$, but now I give up:) you're right